# How would I write the following in R?

Tags: r

```
"red", "red", "red", "green", "green", "blue"
```

I have tried using `rep`, etc but I can only get one the colors.

> use `rep` and/or `c`, twice at most, each with a max of 2 arguments.

Comment: is this homework? check out the `times` argument in `?rep` ...

Comment: Try c(rep('red', 3), rep('green', 2), rep('blue', 1))

Comment: cant use rep 3 times

Comment: what about c( c( rep("red", 3), rep("green", 2) ) , "blue")?

Comment: yeah that works! thanks jake

Answer (score 5):

```
rep(c("red", "green", "blue"), c(3, 2, 1))
```